# How to identify if a compound is organic or inorganic?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the actual basis of distinction of organic compounds? The presence of carbon is not the only basis.

Comment: This isn't trivial nor standardised. Check out [my answer to a different question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/39251/7475). And you might also be interested in [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18/7475)

Comment: There's also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/what-is-the-definition-of-organic-compounds

Comment: In short, if you read of it in an organic chemistry textbook, it is organic.

Comment: The organic compound consists of C-C or C-H bonds.