# What criteria have to be met to term a carboxylic acid a 'fatty acid'?

Tags: organic-chemistry

So we were doing the chapter *Biomolecules* in class the other day, and my teacher told us that every carboxylic acid that consists of an aliphatic chain and a **total** carbon atom count that's **four** or more, is a fatty acid.

Now owing to my teacher's (rather annoying) habit of grossly over-simplifying things, I decided to look up 'fatty acids' in my trusty Oxford Science Dictionary (printed in 2003). According to it,

> Chain length ranges from one hydrogen atom (in methanoic acid) to nearly 30 carbon atoms.

But a quick Wikipedia search, gives me this:

> Most naturally occurring fatty acids have an unbranched chain of an even number of carbon atoms, from 4 to 28.

So now I'm *completely* lost. Fine, chuck what my teacher said, but the *other* two sources *seem* to contradict each other. So I'd really appreciate it, if someone can help me get the following straight (I'd prefer a *reliable* source, if you're citing anything):

**Q1: What is the *minimum* number of carbons in a carboxylic acid as a *whole* (includes the carboxyl group)? So is methanoic acid or butanoic acid that's the smallest fatty acid?**

**Q2: Is there an 'upper limit' on the *total* carbon atom count for fatty acids? As in; can I synthesize, say, an 80 carbon aliphatic carboxylic acid and still *correctly* call it a fatty acid?**

**Q3: Is there any *other* criterion that's necessary to classify something as a fatty acid that hasn't been mentioned by my teacher or the other sources? If so, what is it?**

Comment: I think trying to come up with a specific definition of what's a fatty acid is a *slippery* affair. See [Is activated carbon classified as organic or inorganic?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18/11)

Comment: The old adage about tomatoes comes to mind: *"Knowledge is knowing a tomato is a fruit; wisdom is not putting it in a fruit salad."* Likewise, wisdom would be not referring to methanoic/ethanoic acid as "fatty acids", regardless of if they technically meet the definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to consult the [IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology](http://goldbook.iupac.org/index.html), aka the *Gold Book* for a definition of [fatty acids](http://goldbook.iupac.org/F02330.html)!

In a **narrow** sense, fatty acids are defined as

> aliphatic monocarboxylic acids derived from or contained in esterified form in an animal or vegetable fat, oil or wax.

The definition continues to mention that

> natural fatty acids commonly have a chain of 4 to 28 carbons […]

The paragraph closes with a wider definition, namely:

> By extension, the term is sometimes used to embrace all acyclic aliphatic carboxylic acids.

---

Personally, I have used the term *fatty acids* only for natural fatty acids.

Comment: So in other words, the Oxford dictionary is incorrect?

Comment: @AaronAbraham I think that the definition in the dictionary is somewhat half arsed and arbitrary. I'd go with the Golden Book. Note that they mention that natural fatty acids **commonly** have up to 28 carbons. This is very reasonable and doesn't exclude compounds like lacceroic acid, which has been isolated from plants, from the family of natural fatty acids.

Comment: And I have even heard colleagues use the term for *hydroxylated* linear acyclic aliphatic carboxylic acids. On that note, I would have added the adjective *linear*, too; but I realise the term is not defined well.